# Getting Error when running Django Test on Heroku CI

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-ci

I am using DRF and the tests are written for the APIs. I want to run those test on heroku and also use the CI in my pipeline for the development environment.

When default SQLlite db is used in the config, the error that I am getting -

Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.

My code and configs

test_*.py

```
class TestUser(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def test_user(self):
    ...
```

base.py file

```
db_config = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=False)
DATABASES_AVAILABLE = {
    'test': db_config,
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

database = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DATABASE_TEST', 'sqlite')
DATABASES = {
    'default': DATABASES_AVAILABLE[database]
}

# Database Configuration Ends
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

In Heroku CI Configs, I have

```
DJANGO_DATABASE_TEST : test
```

app.json

```
{
  "buildpacks": [{ "url": "heroku/python" }],
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "env": { "POSTGRESQL_VERSION": "10" },
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
      "scripts": {
        "test": "./manage.py migrate && ./manage.py  test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Error that I am getting in heroku ci

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

### update 1:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())


db_config = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=False)
DATABASES_AVAILABLE = {
    'test': db_config,
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

database = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DATABASE_TEST', 'sqlite')
DATABASES = {
    'default': DATABASES_AVAILABLE[database]
}
```

if I move  `django_heroku.settings(locals(), databases=True)` before the `DATABASE` then I am getting this error

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: role "postgres" does not exist
```

### Resources I have referred -

1. https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/17, 2) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql, 3) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Part of your problem is probably that you're using `django-heroku`, which is abandoned, archived and hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Comment: @TomCarrick Do you recommend any other way to run the test?

Comment: I would start with pulling out django-heroku and seeing if it works. I think you should try that and come back if it still isn't working, as people won't want to help you with support for unsupported libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experiments and reading, I have a solution

created different environments files in Django - `develop`, `productions`, `ci`.

In the `ci` environment i did not include `django_heroku.settings(locals())` and only added the following configurations

```
DEBUG = True
APPEND_SLASH = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres_buildpack_db',
    }
}
```

and in the app.json file

```
{
  "buildpacks": [{ "url": "heroku/python" }],
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "env": { "POSTGRESQL_VERSION": "10" },
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "./manage.py migrate && ./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username='admin' --email='admin@admin.com'",
        "test": "./manage.py migrate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`django_heroku.settings(locals())` is setting the Db SLL connection to true, and indyno db does not support SSL, so removed it in in CI env.

Finally all the tests ran in the Heroku-CI. Phew!